# ABS builds but Gradle error: does not exists in my project

Tags: migration, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I started using android-studio today, trying to import from eclipse. i followed http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html migrate from eclipse steps from Google.

I then Import Module -> from source for ABS, and Module-> Dependencies, added android-supportv4, google-play-services_lib, and actionbarsherlock (all the libs that i need).

ABS compiles find on its own as a module. but when i try to compile the project, i get

```
Gradle: error: package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
Gradle: error: package com.actionbarsherlock.view does not exist
Gradle: error: package com.actionbarsherlock.view does not exist
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class SherlockFragment
...
```

I have no idea what's going on, i am not getting any REDS nor error normally, and when i hover over sherlockfragment and such, it finds it. But when it compiles i get that error.

I have read through other stackoverflow post but still so confuse on what's going on.

I DO NOT have a build.gradle in ABS.
My project's build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Do i need to reference the ABS in here?

Thanks guys,
Kev

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you setup the dependencies between your main module and ABS through the Studio/IntelliJ UI. This does not work.

Since Studio delegate building to Gradle, the dependencies needs to be setup in build.gradle, and ABS needs to be built with Gradle as well.

With that setup, importing the project in Studio will configure Studio automatically to use the same dependencies when dealing with code-completion, static analysis and refactoring.